# explicit algorithm for spanning tree protocol for simulation

Tags: networking, routes, minimum-spanning-tree, switching

I need a short and explicit step by step algorithm as a function for spanning tree protocol to be implemented in my simulation that input the adjacent matrix of a network graph and output approximately the same tree as the spanning tree protocol result in Ethernet switches. other variants of STP protocols like RSTP or MSTP are not the goal here.

Comment: Spanning tree _is_ the algorithm. The _IEEE 802.1D, IEEE Standard for
Local and metropolitan area networks, Media Access Control (MAC) Bridges_ has the algorithm in Section 8.

Comment: yes i already know that standard exist however its full of details, i need a short algorithm that contains all the idea of STP which is run centrally as a separate function for an existing graph.

Comment: Unless you use the STP algorithm, you will not come up with the same answer that STP will. There are lots of parts to the decision on how an interface ends up as a root, designated, or blocking interface. You will need to communicate all the variables from switch to switch before the loop-free path resolves.

Comment: its ok even if these details are ignored, i would relaxed 'exactly' expression in my question.

Comment: For instance, if you connect two switches with two links, you need to determine which is active, and which is not. That requires a lot of information, down to, and including, the switch port number. That is why there are so many fields in the BPDUs.

Comment: switch port numbers can be an argument passed to the STP function as an array in addition to the adjacent matrix. since non active ports are doesnt affect the result of STP , we can make the graph adjacent matrix based on active port and only pass active ports to the stp function. this stp function.

Comment: Right, but my point is that all the information in the BPDUs must be communicated between the switches in order to determine if a link is root, designated, or blocking. This is the STP algorithm, and it is a simple as possible. There is nothing unnecessary in the STP algorithm, and the IEEE lays it out for you.

Comment: i don't object that this algorithm is old and outdated. however nowhere addressed a simple code to be used in simulation and it would be great if someone do it.